# What is the best way to fetch/render one-to-many relationships?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models which look like that:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
dataname = models.TextField()
datadesc = models.TextField()
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class EntryFile(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
    datafile = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/%Y/%m/%d/%H-%M-%S")
```

I want to render all the entries with their related files for a specific user.
Now I am doing it that way in my view to get the values:

```
    entries = Entry.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by("-timestamp")
    files = {}
    for entry in entries:
        entryfiles = EntryFile.objects.filter(entry=entry)
        files[entry] = entryfiles
    return render_to_response("index.html", {'user': request.user, 'entries': entries, 'files': files, 'message': message})
```

But I am not able/don't know how to work with these data in my template. This what I do now, but isn't working:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    <td>{{ entry.datadesc }}</td>
    <td><table>
        {{ files.entry }}
        {% for file in files.entry %}
        <td>{{ file.datafile.name|split:"/"|last }}</td>
        <td>{{ file.datafile.size|filesizeformat }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ object.datafile.url }}">download</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url main.views.delete object.id %}">delete</a></td>
        {% endfor %}
    </table></td>
{% endfor %}
```

Anyone can tell me if I am doing it the right way in view and then how to access these data in the template?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cut your view code to this line:

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by("-timestamp")
```

And do this in the template:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    <td>{{ entry.datadesc }}</td>
    <td><table>
    {% for file in entry.entryfile_set.all %}
        <td>{{ file.datafile.name|split:"/"|last }}</td>
        <td>{{ file.datafile.size|filesizeformat }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ object.datafile.url }}">download</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url main.views.delete object.id %}">delete</a></td>
    {% endfor %}
    </table></td>
{% endfor %}
```

I am a big fan of using [`related_name`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) in Models, however, so you could change this line:

```
entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
```

To this:

```
entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, related_name='files')
```

And then you can access all the files for a particular entry by changing this:

```
{% for file in files.entryfile_set.all %}
```

To the more readable/obvious:

```
{% for file in entry.files.all %}
```

Comment: No problem. Welcome to the site.